# Определение города по IP

Tags: geoip, ip

Здравствуйте

Существуют ли сервисы или методы с точным определением города по IP?
Испробовал [IpGeoBase](http://ipgeobase.ru/) и [GEO Zone Query](http://www.gzq.ru/), определение плохое.

Спасибо!

Comment: На 2ip [есть такой сервис](http://2ip.ru/geoip/). Там, правда без API.

Comment: [GeoLite Free Downloadable Databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) есть и платная версия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую Вам прочитать эту статью [Определение города по IP-адресу](http://habrahabr.ru/post/26788/).
Да и вообще сайт очень полезный и интересный

Answer (score 1):

Так как вопрос звучал как «существуют ли сервисы или методы...», то вот пример подобного сервиса: [The entire geolocation base of Ipv4, Ipv6, domain names](https://location.ekolesnyk.com). Если верить описанию на сайте, он предоставляет следующие возможности:

- API геолокации по странам и городам по IPv4, IPv6 и доменным именам;
- API для определения VPN-адресов;
- API оконечных узлов и провайдеров;
- API адресов из чёрных списков.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, чтобы он не выглядел как реклама сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуюсь API от https://ipwhois.io/ru/ , в целом устраивает. Точность нормальная.